# Google App Script new editor - string property double underlined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, ide

Probably a nube question but I have a line of code:

`var c = message.substring(i, i + 1);`

It works but in the new Google App Script editor, the string property "substring" has a double-underline under it, which seems to suggest that it's wrong, but it actually works!

"Show Fixes" gives me only two options - to ignore the "error" or disable checking, neither of which seems like what I want to do. Any ideas?

Comment: `substr()` or `substring()`?

Comment: substring - it works but the editor doesn't like it. Seems like "var message = spreadsheet.getRange("A2").getValue();" sets message to something other than a string. If I tack +""; on to the end it likes it then but that seems naff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is due to how the variable "message" is defined. I did a quick test trying to replicate your scenario and this is what I got:

With warning:

```
var message = 0
message = '123456789'
var c = message.substr(1, 5);
```

Without warning:

```
var message = '0'
message = '123456789'
var c = message.substr(1, 5);
```

Both cases have the same result without errors. If you provide more code I can check why the warning is appearing.

edit:

As you have said in the comments, your variable is being defined from the `range` of a `SpreadSheet` using `getValue()`, this method returns an object with the value of the `cell`. If you want to obtain a string you should use `getDisplayValue()`. You can also use the built-in method `toString()` to make sure that any variable is converted into a string.

References:

- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())
- [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue())

Comment: Thanks! The variable is defined thus:
var message = spreadsheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
If I change it to:
var message = "bob";
the error goes.

Comment: So if I initialise message
  var message = "";
then the error goes. Still confused why
 spreadsheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
doesn't return a recognised string.

Comment: OK this fixes it but I don't like it
  var message = spreadsheet.getRange("A2").getValue()+"";
Basically adding a null string tells message it's a string. Anything more elegant, please?!

Comment: There are two more elegant options to make the error go away:
getRange('A1').getValue().toString() or getRange('A1').getDisplayValue()

Comment: Thanks @fullfine! I thought I'd tried that but the `.toString()` does the trick and also makes sense so double win. Also learnt how to mark up code as above. Getting there :)

Comment: I am glad that you learnt something valuable. If my answer was useful please mark it as accepted so the community will know that it helped you.